# Xcode error "value of type '[UIViewController]' has no member 'firstObject'"

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, syntax-error

I am attempting to create a Swift version of [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/nmattisson/DropdownMenu). I started by doing a literal transfer of all the code from Objective-C to Swift, which caused a lot of errors (60 something in a 321 line file).

For this specific line of code

```
self.currentViewController = self.childViewControllers.firstObject
```

I am getting this error:

```
Value of type '[UIViewController]' has no member 'firstObject'
```

I have tried adding `as! UIViewController`, and placing exclamation points and question marks at most of locations possible. None of the things I tried from the suggested posts helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just called `first` on Swift arrays.

```
self.currentViewController = self.childViewControllers.first
```